# Save a Thrift struct to a file using Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, thrift

I was wondering if there is a nice way to save a Thrift struct to a file/SQLite using iOS's Core Data.

One way is to do the mapping manually between the Thrift declaration and Entities in Core Data, but that's a lot of work and is not very easy to maintain.

A second idea is to save the Thrift as a binary data field in an Entity.

Is there a more elegant way? E.g., a library that takes in a Thrift and takes care of this business?

Thank you,
Silviu

Comment: Hi silviu! Did you found some solution, maybe wrote orm or got a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NSValue to wrap structures.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/Values.html) In turn, [NSValue objects can be stored in a transformable attribute.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html)

However, if you want to search or manipulate the contents of struct within Core Data, then you should model the struct as an entity and provide a method in the custom subclass to return the struct if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't see a clear difference between what you suggested and my second idea. What I ended up doing is creating an Entity that has attributes for my search criteria and another attribute for the encoded version of a Thrift structure.

Comment: There isn't any existing library most likely because it isn't worth the effort. Saving as NSValue allows you access parts of the structure without further conversion. It's the preferred means within the API. NSValue exist largely to wrap scalar values of all kinds. I almost always create an entity because you usually need to fetch or search on the values of the members of the struct